# snprintf causing Abort trap 6 within function but not in main

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am having trouble understanding why this code executes the way it does. I fail to understand why when doThings executes, it gives me an Abort trap: 6 error, but when the loop within main executes, it does not give me an error and prints the valid portion of my character array (the value that can fit inside an array of size 30, the literal is 31 chars).

In short, the error is in the snprintf statement within doThings. Commenting it out breaks the code (obviously) but the Abort trap 6 does not occur. But why does it result in an an error there while executing without error in main?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_LEN 30

void doThings(char *buffer)
{
    char anotherBuffer[BUF_LEN];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= BUF_LEN; i++)
    {
        char temp[2];

        snprintf(temp, 2, "%s", buffer + i);

        strcat(anotherBuffer, temp);
    }

    printf("%s\n", anotherBuffer);

 }

int main()
{

    char aString[BUF_LEN] = "1234567890123456789012345678901";

    printf("%s\n", aString);

    //This is doThings within main
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= BUF_LEN; i++)
    {
        char temp[2];

        snprintf(temp, 2, "%s", aString + i);

        printf("%s", temp);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Now execute doThings passing aString
    doThings(aString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(anotherBuffer, temp);` is done before initializing `anotherBuffer`.  That leads to UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by saying

```
  char aString[BUF_LEN] = "1234567890123456789012345678901";
```

you're supplying a list of 31 `char`s as initializer to a 30-char array. That's not wrong as it is, but trying to use that `char` array as a *string* will lead to UB as there's no null-terminator in place.

Either define `BUF_LEN` as 32, or let the compiler decide the size, use something like

```
  char aString[ ] = "1234567890123456789012345678901";
```

where compiler picks the correct size for the array as per the length of the supplied initializer, including the terminating null.

Then again, I believe, it has also to do with your looping condition. Instead of

```
 for (i = 0; i <= BUF_LEN; i++)
```

you should do

```
 for (i = 0; i < BUF_LEN; i++)
```

Otherwise, you'll be [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) as C arrays use 0-based indexing. By this, you'll be accessing out of bound memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, as rightly mentioned by [Chux in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334281/snprintf-causing-abort-trap-6-within-function-but-not-in-main/40334326#comment67923813_40334281), you are using

```
 strcat(anotherBuffer, temp);
```

while `anotherBuffer` is uninitialized. By definition, the first argument of `strcat()` should be a pointer to a *string*, i.e., pointer to a null-terminated `char` array. At the very beginning, the content of `anotherBuffer` is indeterminate, let alone having a null-terminator. You should be initializing the automatic local variables always, like in this case,

```
char anotherBuffer[BUF_LEN] = {0};
```

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, sorry. A lot of the fixes proposed in your reply such as initializing my character array and removing the initialized size of aString do not change the behavior of the program. However, if I declare (and initialize) a char array `aNewBuffer` in main and change the print statement to `strcat(aNewBuffer, temp)` and `printf("%s", aNewBuffer)`, the execution of `main()` results in an `Abort trap: 6` as the function does. This now poses the question; why do `snprintf()` and `strcat()` result in this error when using `printf()` to print the temporary string does not?

Comment: Declaring `anotherBuffer` as size `BUF_LEN + 1` results in execution without error. Thank you!